# Sum datediff in minutes with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of tasks where I enter when I started a task tStart and when I ended the task tEnd. I would like to know how many minutes of work I spent on tasks over a period of time.  So whats wrong with this query?

```
SELECT SUM(MINUTE(DATEDIFF(tEnd, tStart)))
FROM tasks
WHERE tStart >= '2011-04-04'
    AND tEnd <= '2011-04-04'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your condition

```
WHERE tStart >= '2011-04-04' AND tEnd <= '2011-04-04'
```

Pretty much **ensures** that the only records that will be left are where

```
tStart = tEnd = '2011-04-04'
```

It goes without saying that DATEDIFF between them gives 0, for a grand total sum of 0.  In fact, DATEDIFF **ignores** the time portion, so you need to use TIMEDIFF + TIME_TO_SEC

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(tEnd, tStart))/60)
FROM tasks
WHERE tStart >= '2011-04-04' AND tEnd <= adddate('2011-04-04', interval 1 day)
```

Notice the change to the WHERE clause. If you are trying to say, started any time today and ended any time today, then the range should be *(already assuming start < end)*

```
WHERE tStart >= '2011-04-04'
  AND tEnd < adddate('2011-04-04', interval 1 day)
```

You can hard code it to 2011-04-05, but using `<` (less than) and adding one day to the end limit is what I am showing here.

Comment: so how do i get total number of minutes for a single day 2011-04-04 or lets say a week 2011-03-12 to 2011-03-27 ?

Comment: This still results in 0 SELECT SUM(MINUTE(DATEDIFF(tEnd, tStart))) FROM tasks WHERE tStart >= '2011-04-04' AND tEnd < adddate('2011-04-04', interval 1 day)

Comment: @User / Ah.. just realised DATEDIFF **ignores** the time portion, so you get 0 days. You wanted TIMEDIFF + TIME_TO_SEC