# MS-SQL DATEDIFF GROUP BY To show hours for each jobcode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, datediff

I have been thrown in over my head with some MS SQL work and am humbly requesting assistance. I am learning the basics but was given an assignment far above my skill level. I have been asked to provide a query that will show how many hours have been worked for each jobcode using our timeclock database. Below is a sample of the table.

```
employeeid  Jobcode      TimeIn               TimeOut
18405          4    2014-08-08 06:55:00 2014-08-08 09:14:00
19000          4    2014-08-08 09:27:00 2014-08-08 11:04:00
20205          4    2014-08-08 11:33:00 NULL
18406         13    2014-08-08 06:57:00 2014-08-08 09:01:00
18405         13    2014-08-08 09:16:00 2014-08-08 11:03:00
18406         13    2014-08-08 11:33:00 NULL
18407         19    2014-08-08 08:25:00 2014-08-08 12:03:00
18411         19    2014-08-08 07:59:00 2014-08-08 11:01:00
```

What I want to be displayed is the total hours for each jobcode at the time the query is run.

```
 Job Code     Minutes
    1         500
    2         700
    3         200
```

Here is the query I working with :

```
select eh.jobcode,  datediff(mi, eh.TimeIn, isnull(eh.TimeOut, DateAdd(HH,2,Getdate())))   as Minutes

FROM [TimeClockPlus].[dbo].EmployeeHours as eh  inner join 
[TimeClockPlus].    [dbo].employeelist as el ON eh.employeeid = el.employeeid   

WHERE el.department = 'WAREHOUSE' and eh.timein  
>= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
and eh.timein < dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), +1)

Group by  datediff(mi, eh.TimeIn, isnull(eh.TimeOut, DateAdd(HH,2,Getdate()))) , eh.Jobcode
```

But I am getting multiple rows for each jobcode, am I not understanding GROUP BY correctly?

Example of results with  'order by eh.jobcode'  added on the end:

```
jobcode Minutes
   1    69
   1    127
   1    112
   1    24
   1    105
   2    134
   2    53
   2    101
   4    80
   4    9
   4    105
   4    94
   4    129
   4    119
   5    15
   5    103
   5    23
   5    28
   5    33
   5    91
```

Comment: Both of the below posters had the right answer technically. I just needed to do a sum on the datediff and remove it from the group by.     `SELECT eh.jobcode, SUM( DATEDIFF(mi, eh.TimeIn, ISNULL(eh.TimeOut,       DATEADD(HH,2,GETDATE()))) )AS Minutes

FROM [TimeClockPlus].[dbo].EmployeeHours AS eh inner join [TimeClockPlus].[dbo].employeelist AS el ON eh.employeeid = el.employeeid   
  
WHERE el.department = 'WAREHOUSE' AND eh.timein  >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
and eh.timein < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), +1) 

GROUP BY  eh.Jobcode `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to me that you have employee IDs using the same Job Code which is why you get duplicates. To get around this, I suggest you use the `datediff(minute` function in order to get the minutes but also total it by using the `SUM()` function in the select statement if that makes sense.

If you can't apply `SUM(datediff(minute` maybe try looking into this:

[Sum datediff in minutes with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545978/sum-datediff-in-minutes-with-mysql)

Comment: When I try to wrap the datediff in a sum it errors saying : Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.  I will look at that link and try to adapt my query. I also edited the initial table to show that multiple employees are using the same jobcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost done. I believe it's enough if you group by the jobcode and add a sum over the datediff. If you want it to look good you can build your select with datediff in a CTE and do the group by and sum on your newly created CTE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you saying I should change the select and group by sections to be like this :  SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, eh.TimeIn, ISNULL   (eh.TimeOut,GETDATE()))) AS Hours                                When I run this it errors saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."